# Error while uploading file to the server after deployment c# mvc

Tags: c#, file, uploading

I'm creating an app in c# mvc, where users can upload mp3 files, Below is my Upload controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        string x = Request["ss"];

        song std = new song();

        if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
            try
            {
               // string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Songs"), Path.GetFileName(file.FileName)); 
               string path = "~/Songs/" + Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                var allowedExtensions = new[] { ".mp3",".MP3" };
                var extension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);

                if (!allowedExtensions.Contains(extension))
                {
                    ViewBag.Message = "Only .mp3 extension files are allowed!!";
                }
                else
                {
                    file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(@"~\Songs\" + file.FileName));
                    //file.SaveAs(path);
                    string[] arr = { };
                    arr = (file.FileName).Split('.');
                    std.name = arr[0];
                    if (x == null || x == "")
                    {
                        std.artist = "Not Mentioned";
                    }
                    else {
                        std.artist = x;
                    }
                    std.likes = "0";
                    std.dislikes = "0";

                    repo4.save4(std);       //call the function..

                    ViewBag.Message = "Song uploaded successfully!! ";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "ERROR:" + ex.Message.ToString();
            }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "You have not specified a file.";
        }
        return View();
    }
```

below is my view for index.cshtml:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("index", "Upload", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype ="multipart/form-data" }))
            {

                <label class="l" for="file">Upload Song:</label>
                <input class="l" type="file" name="file" id="file" />

                <div class="form-inline form-group">
                    <label class="l">Artist' Name : &nbsp;</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ss" maxlength="30" placeholder="Leave it blank if u want.." />
                </div>

                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" value="Upload" />

                <div class="text-danger">@ViewBag.Message</div><br /><div class="text-success">Search uploaded song <a href="/Reg/reg">HERE</a></div>
            }
```

Now, I'm saving the mp3 files to a folder named as Songs..this code seems to be working fine when i build my project on VS..but after deployment on app harbor, when i try to upload an mp3 file i keep getting following error:

> ERROR:Access to the path
>   'D:\Users\apphb180c99d1921484\app_PublishedWebsites\WebMatrixWebsite\Songs\Wake
>   Me Up.mp3' is denied.

Please any help would be appreciated as i cant get my head around it..thanx!!

Comment: What Trust level is the website running with on App Harbor? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754779.aspx

Comment: sorry i'm quite new to .NET and i dnt knw how to determine that :(

Comment: Unfortunately I have never used App Harbor, it would be somewhere in your website or IIS settings if you can control it.  You might be able to specify it in your web.config. Also, does the Songs folder exist?   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wyts434y%28v=vs.140%29.aspx

Comment: yep..it works perfectly fine on localhost..i'm able to upload and play the song however it's not working on the server for some reason..

Comment: it's working now..i gave permissions for NETWORK SERVICE to the Songs folder..working like a charm now..:)

Answer (score 1):

Working for me now..in case anyone's still wondering how..you need to give permissions for NETWORK SERVICE to your folder where the files are being stored..

In this case:

**Songs->properties**..open the **security tab -> edit -> Add**..

choose the Locations.. to your pc..then write **"NETWORK SERVICE"** under "enter the object names to select" then check names and enter ok...

now give it the permissions by selecting one of the check boxes, you might wanna choose read/write..

I chose **"full control"** and it's working perfectly for me..hopefully it'll work out for you guys too :) cheers..

Comment: Thanks Daniyal, +1 to you, your suggestion worked for me, though its a very common problem.